# There is an issue when i add "?" in base URL in Karate . How to resolve it?

Tags: karate

```
Background:
 * url "https://abc.testrail.net/index.php?"

Scenario: : Create CHECK


 Given path'/api/v2/get_case/121'
 And header Content-Type = 'application/json'
 When method GET
 Then print response
```

The following is the url which the API hits when i run the above code 
 https://abc.testrail.net/index.php/api/v2/get_case/121?

The expected url is https://abc.testrail.net/index.php?/api/v2/get_case/121

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is an un-usual (and in my opinion a badly-designed) URL-scheme, please don't use `path` and form the URL manually. This is not an issue with Karate.

```
Background:
 * def baseUrl = "https://freshwave.testrail.net/index.php?/api/v2/"

Scenario: : Create CHECK        
 Given url baseUrl + 'get_case/121'
 And header Content-Type = 'application/json'
 When method GET
 Then print response
```